# Can I install Pow on my Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rack-pow

I find Pow great on my Mac. It makes the Rails dev environment setup easy. Can I install it on my Ubuntu? I can't find any info about it. If not, is there anything like it for Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pow (specifically) cannot be installed on anything except a Mac at this time. It uses [plists](https://github.com/37signals/pow/blob/master/src/cx.pow.firewall.plist.eco) for launching and managing the firewall, and uses some OS X `/etc/resolver` trickery to resolve the domain names. See [this post](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2421186) for a bit more detail.

Comment: Any `Pow` alternative exist?

Comment: Yup. I'm looking for an alternative also. I'm trying thin server now, but pow is really zero-configuration stuff.

Comment: @Dmitry, @goo - You're looking for `prax`. See @Richard Smith's post below for link.

Answer (score 26):

There is now a linux equivalent: [prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax)

Comment: Chrome has stopped support prax :(

Comment: @RAJ dnsmasq fixed it again

Answer (score 13):

I was searching for the same thing and I found [hoof](https://github.com/pyromaniac/hoof/).

Comment: [discontinued. Author recomends Prax now](https://github.com/pyromaniac/hoof/#sorry-guys-the-project-is-not-maintained-anymore-but-good-news-there-is-githubcomysbaddadenprax--)

Answer (score 9):

I've been using [hoof](https://github.com/pyromaniac/hoof/) and it works, but its definitely a bit rough around the edges.

There is a [Linux fork of Pow](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/pow) that looks interesting. I haven't tried it for myself yet but I'm hoping that it will get pushed upstream into the [main Pow code](http://github.com/37signals/pow).

Comment: Sadly it won't happen: since Pow authors have no interests into a Linux port, it was merely a hack in the coffeescript code, plus a few dnsmasq and resvolconf conf. It used to work but it failed on me a few weeks ago. Since then i've been working on a pure ruby alternative: https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax which still has a long way to go.

Comment: It's sad that they have no interest in supporting Linux but great to hear you're working on an alternative. I'll keep my eye on [prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax).

Answer (score 2):

How about using [passenger standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented BAM! Heavily inspired by pow, BAM! goes further by supporting not only ruby/rack applications, but any Procfile-based application. Also, BAM! is planned to support both Linux and Mac OS X. Please, give it a try!

https://github.com/jweslley/bam